# Information about Disk Storage MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, mysqladmin

I am trying to create an application for monitoring MySQL,in my application there's a part of  monitor **DISK STORAGE**, so after more research I have not found how to calculate :

- used and free size of tablespace,
- used and free of data files,
- used and free of log files

Anyone know how to calculate their sizes or someone can give me articles or books can help me.
And Thanks.

Comment: Is this all about InnoDB, MyISAM, or both ???

Comment: No, about all the server because I monitor the server but it's possible !? or their sizes just concerned the InnoDB. Thanks

Comment: Are you using innodb_file_per_table ???

Comment: Yes I use innodb_file_per_table :)

Comment: Both about innodb and MyISAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query I use to get all the used space of MySQL for all storage engines:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(ENGINE,'Total') "Storage Engine",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(DAT/POWER(1024,pw1),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw1*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Data Size",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(NDX/POWER(1024,pw2),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw2*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Index Size",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(TBL/POWER(1024,pw3),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw3*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Total Size"
FROM
(
    SELECT ENGINE,DAT,NDX,TBL,
    IF(px>4,4,px) pw1,IF(py>4,4,py) pw2,IF(pz>4,4,pz) pw3
    FROM 
    (SELECT *,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(DAT=0,1,DAT))/LOG(1024)) px,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(NDX=0,1,NDX))/LOG(1024)) py,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(TBL=0,1,TBL))/LOG(1024)) pz
        FROM
        (SELECT
            ENGINE,
            SUM(data_length) DAT,
            SUM(index_length) NDX,
            SUM(data_length+index_length) TBL
        FROM
        (
           SELECT engine,data_length,index_length FROM
           information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN
           ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')
           AND ENGINE IS NOT NULL
        ) AAA GROUP BY ENGINE WITH ROLLUP
) AAA ) AA) A,(SELECT ' BKBMBGBTB' units) B;
```

By Database

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(DB,'Total') "Database",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(DAT/POWER(1024,pw1),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw1*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Data Size",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(NDX/POWER(1024,pw2),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw2*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Index Size",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(TBL/POWER(1024,pw3),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw3*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Total Size"
FROM
(
    SELECT DB,DAT,NDX,TBL,
    IF(px>4,4,px) pw1,IF(py>4,4,py) pw2,IF(pz>4,4,pz) pw3
    FROM 
    (SELECT *,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(DAT=0,1,DAT))/LOG(1024)) px,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(NDX=0,1,NDX))/LOG(1024)) py,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(TBL=0,1,TBL))/LOG(1024)) pz
    FROM
    (SELECT
        DB,
        SUM(data_length) DAT,
        SUM(index_length) NDX,
        SUM(data_length+index_length) TBL
    FROM
    (
       SELECT table_schema DB,data_length,index_length FROM
       information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN
       ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')
       AND ENGINE IS NOT NULL
    ) AAA GROUP BY DB WITH ROLLUP
) AAA) AA) A,(SELECT ' BKBMBGBTB' units) B;
```

By Database/Storage Engine

```
SELECT
    IF(ISNULL(DB)+ISNULL(ENGINE)=2,'Database Total',
    CONCAT(DB,' ',IFNULL(ENGINE,'Total'))) "Reported Statistic",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(DAT/POWER(1024,pw1),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw1*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Data Size",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(NDX/POWER(1024,pw2),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw2*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Index Size",
    LPAD(CONCAT(FORMAT(TBL/POWER(1024,pw3),2),' ',
    SUBSTR(units,pw3*2+1,2)),17,' ') "Total Size"
FROM
(
    SELECT DB,ENGINE,DAT,NDX,TBL,
    IF(px>4,4,px) pw1,IF(py>4,4,py) pw2,IF(pz>4,4,pz) pw3
    FROM 
    (SELECT *,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(DAT=0,1,DAT))/LOG(1024)) px,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(NDX=0,1,NDX))/LOG(1024)) py,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(TBL=0,1,TBL))/LOG(1024)) pz
    FROM
    (SELECT
        DB,ENGINE,
        SUM(data_length) DAT,
        SUM(index_length) NDX,
        SUM(data_length+index_length) TBL
    FROM
    (
       SELECT table_schema DB,ENGINE,data_length,index_length FROM
       information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN
       ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')
       AND ENGINE IS NOT NULL
    ) AAA GROUP BY DB,ENGINE WITH ROLLUP
) AAA) AA) A,(SELECT ' BKBMBGBTB' units) B;
```

## CAVEAT ON InnoDB FRAGMENTATION

To find the fragmentation of an individual InnoDB table (`.ibd`) you cannot fully trust the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database. You have to piggyback off the OS.

Let's say the table is `mydb.mtable` and datadir is `/var/lib/mysql`

Get the Size of the InnoDB Table from OS and subtract it from what INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables says

```
SQLSTMT="SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) size FROM information_schema.tables"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable'"
FILESIZE_OS=`ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd | awk '{print $5}'`
FILESIZE_DB=`mysql -uroot -ppassword -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
(( FILESIZE_FRAG = FILESIZE_OS - FILESIZE_DB ))
```

## CAVEAT ON MyISAM FRAGMENTATION

For the MyISAM table `mydb.myatble` for the `.MYD`

```
SELECT data_length INTO @datsize
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb'
AND table_name='mytable';
SELECT table_rows*avg_row_length INTO @sizerows
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb'
AND table_name='mytable';
SET @tblfrag = @datsize - @sizerows;
SELECT @datsize,@sizerows,@tblfrag;
```

## CAVEAT ON Tablespace file ibdata1

Here is a look at the InnoDB Architecture

[image]

Please note that ibdata1 has 5 moving parts

- Data Dictionary
- Double Write Buffer (support data consistency; used for Crash Recovery)
- Insert Buffer (Buffers Changes to Secondary Non-Unique Indexes)
- Rollback Segments
- [Undo Space (where the most uncontrolled growth can happen)](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/06/10/reasons-for-run-away-main-innodb-tablespace/)

Since you have [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled, the data and index pages for all InnoDB have been separated from these internal parts. Thus, there is no need to monitor ibdata1 internally.

For the benefit of those who have [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled, then everything InnoDB and its grandmother is inside ibdata1. This is how you monitor ibdata1:

Let's say your [innodb_data_fie_path](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_data_file_path) is this

```
[mysqld]
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
```

You would have to add the file sizes of the two files and subtract the sum of the data and index pages. Perhaps like this:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
IBDATA_SIZE=0
for X in `ls -l ibdata* | awk '{print $5}'` ; do (( IBDATA_SIZE += X )) ; done
SQLSTMT="SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length)"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM information_schema.tables"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE engine='InnoDB'"
INNODB_SIZE=`mysql -uroot -ppassword -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
(( IBDATA_FRAG = IBDATA_SIZE - INNODB_SIZE ))
```

See my additional suggestion on handling multiple ibdata files : [How to solve "The table ... is full" with "innodb_file_per_table"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/how-to-solve-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table/43577#43577)

Comment: +100 that's great, These statistics can help me a lot. Thanks.
if I want do this statistics like this :
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3q2DOPnNwNhaUZEVXJZeDRMTm8/edit
What is the formula to make it and Thanks again.

Comment: I have to leave work now. I can look at this in about 4.5 - 5 hours...

Comment: ok, I wish you good luck and thank you for all