# showing table is full on alter mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In my phpmyadmin , when am adding a new column to my table , mysql throwing me error `table xxx is full`
i also search on google , but did not get help.

am also gone through dba.stackexchange.com answer realeted to this question , but no help. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table-set-to-aut

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/full-table.html

Comment: are you using InnoDB ?

Comment: You have a database admin problem, not a programming one, so you should ask this question on the dba site, not here.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your temp folder is full.
you can make a new temp folder where is more space after that let mysql know about your newly created temp folder(dont forget to restart mysql service),
or you can also clear your temp folder, it will work.
you can follow this stackoverflow link for more information [ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'XXX' is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850287/error-1114-hy000-the-table-xxx-is-full)

Comment: Thanks for details `clear your temp folder`

i hit this ubuntu command `sudo find /tmp -type f -atime +10 -delete`
and solved my error